# MsgBox error when trying to use a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code, but for some reason the `msgbox krow` does not seem to work. There is a match but it just shows error. I don't understand why. Help is appreciated, thanks!

```
Sub addsheet()

Dim lrow As Variant, krow As Variant
Dim i As Long, lastcol As Long, lastrow As Long, lastrowcomp As Long
Dim sheetname As String, sheetname2 As String

Sheets("Main Sheet").Activate
lastcol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lrow = Application.Match(Sheets("Main Sheet").Range("F6").Value, Sheets("Main Sheet").Range(Cells(2, 14), Cells(2, lastcol)), 0)

If IsError(lrow) Then
    MsgBox "Please Select a value under change"
ElseIf lrow > 0 Then
    lastrow = Sheets("Main Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, lrow + 13).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrowcomp = Sheets("Comparison Check").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 3 To lastrow
        krow = Application.Match(Sheets("Main Sheet").Cells(i, lrow).Value, Sheets("Comparison Check").Range("A3:A" & lastrowcomp), 0)
        MsgBox krow

        'If IsError(krow) Then
        'sheetname = Sheets("Main Sheet").Cells(i, lrow + 13).Value
        'Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(1)).Name = sheetname
        'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy
        'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetname).Select
        'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetname).Range("A1").Select
        'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetname).Paste
        'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetname).Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
        'Else
        If krow > 0 Then
            sheetname2 = Sheets("Comparison Check").Cells(krow, 1).Value
            Sheets(sheetname2).Activate

        End If
    Next i
End If

End Sub
```

Basically, I am trying to create a new sheet with the name if there is no match and go to the existing sheet if the match exists. but when there is a match it somehow keeps creating a new sheet. Hence, why I added the msgbox krow to confirm the issue was with the matching.

Comment: what is the error thrown?

Comment: is it a type mismatch?

Comment: try casting krow as a string into the message box (should be done automatically anyway, though, so i doubt this will solve your problem)

Comment: Yes indeed it is a type mismatch. Sorry for the late response.

Comment: The above code is missing at least one `Next i` and one `End If`.

Comment: Yep you were right it does not solve the problem. I think it may not be finding a match for some reason?

Comment: @Ralph I have just added the full code and updated it. Before I had pasted only part of the code. Apologies. thanks for the help!

Comment: A title of `I have the following code but for some reason it does not work?` could apply to any of the several million questions here. Would you please replace it with a more useful one? Thanks.

Comment: @Vigmo10 what happens if `krow = Application.Match(Sheets("Main Sheet").Cells(i, lrow).Value, Sheets("Comparison Check").Range("A3:A" & lastrowcomp), 0)` throws and error ? if `Match` fails ? you need to add error handling like `If IsError(krow) Then`

Comment: Just for your consideration: since I read [a speed test comparison review on MATCH vs ARRAY](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/) I have (personally) abandoned the usage of `Application.Match` in my VBA codes altogether and use arrays instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few minor adjustments to your code. Please have a look and let me know if it works now.

```
Option Explicit

Sub addsheet()

Dim lrow As Variant, krow As Variant
Dim i As Long, lastcol As Long, lastrow As Long, lastrowcomp As Long
Dim sheetname As String, sheetname2 As String

Dim ws As Worksheet, lngCount As Long, strSheets As String

strSheets = "Main Sheet/Comparison Check"
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For i = LBound(Split(strSheets, "/")) To UBound(Split(strSheets, "/"))
        If Split(strSheets, "/")(i) = ws.Name Then lngCount = lngCount + 1
    Next i
Next ws
If lngCount < 2 Then
    MsgBox "One of the required sheets was not found." & Chr(10) & "Aborting!"
    Exit Sub
End If

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main Sheet")
    lastcol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lrow = Application.Match(.Range("F6").Value, .Range(.Cells(2, 14), .Cells(2, lastcol)), 0)

    If VarType(lrow) = vbError Then
        MsgBox "Please Select a value under change."
        Debug.Print "Value '" & .Range("F6").Value & "' not found in range " & .Cells(2, 14).Address & ":" & .Cells(2, lastcol).Address
    Else
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, lrow + 13).End(xlUp).Row
        lastrowcomp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Comparison Check").Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 3 To lastrow
            krow = Application.Match(.Cells(i, lrow).Value, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Comparison Check").Range("A3:A" & lastrowcomp), 0)
            If VarType(krow) = vbError Then
                MsgBox CStr(krow)
            Else
                sheetname2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Comparison Check").Cells(krow, 1).Value
                For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                    If ws.Name = sheetname2 Then lngCount = lngCount + 1
                Next ws
                If lngCount < 3 Then
                    MsgBox "A sheet by the name '" & sheetname2 & "'  couldn't be found." & Chr(10) & "Aborting!"
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname2).Activate
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Basically, the above code is almost the same as yours but with much more error handling. So, there are much less assumptions in the code and instead much more checking. If something is not working as intended then you get either a message box or a notification line in the `Immediate Window` of the VBE.

Also, I coded much more explicitly. That means that I am really telling VBA what I want and don't allow for any interpretation. For example: when you wrote `lastcol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` you meant to say that you would like to refer to the last column (`Columns.Count`) of the sheet `Main Sheet`. Yet, this is not explicitly stated in that line and merely inferred by the VBA compiler since you activated the sheet upfront. I changed all of this to explicit coding which eliminates (most of the time) already a lot of trouble.

Comment: Hello mate, apologies for the delayed response. Just tried it, works like a charm, thanks a ton for your help! i will try to code more explicitly from now.